# How can I set a style trigger on the GroupBoxes of my ItemsControl without losing their current style?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, children, groupbox

When I set a style trigger on the children (GroupBoxes) of an ItemsControl the style I've previously applied to GroupBoxes is lost and it renders with default style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the BasedOn property in the new style

This is for using the default style

```
<Style x:Key="newGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
  //...put triggers or whatever you want here         
 </Style>
```

If you want to use a style based on your own style use

`... BasedOn="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyleKey} ...`

Comment: Nice. But is there a way to do it without referencing a style key? My style just targets GroupBox and does not have a key.

Comment: Oh you edited your answer and i didn't notice the change second time round! thank you very much